# All parameters of Get-MsolUser into array

Tags: powershell, reflection, parameters

Want to throw the names of all parameters supported by Get-MsolUser into an array to be able to dynamically get different information from a user.

```
Get-Command Get-MsolUser
```

The command above doesn't show me the parameters, only the command itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following, which simply chains the member-access operator `.`

```
$array = (Get-Command Get-MSolUser).Parameters.Values.Name
```

`Parameters` is a Dictionary object with a built-in `Values` property. That property is a collection that contains attributes about each parameter. Since you only want the name, you can simply access the `Name` property.

If you want to exclude certain parameters, I'd just introduce an exclusion list.

```
$exclude = 'Debug','ErrorAction','ErrorVariable','InformationAction','InformationVariable','OutVariable','OutBuffer','PipelineVariable','Verbose','WarningAction','WarningVariable'

((Get-Command Get-MSolUser).Parameters.Values | Where Name -notin $exclude).Name
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm, but what if I want to exclude the standard PS properties such as ErrorVariable, Verbose and the rest?

Comment: I would just create an array of what you don't want to see. I've added how to do that.